# Given a two variables function, can we know the maximum number of "non-limits" it has?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I came up with a somewhat interesting question: Given a function in two variables in which we are trying to prove the existence of a limit as $(x,y) \to (x_0, y_0)$, it is well known that for some functions, different paths $P_i $ could approach different values $V_i$ and hence, the limit doesn't exist at that point. These $V_i$'s are what I named *"non-limits"*.

But given a function, can we know the maximum number of times this would happen? That is: Can we know the maximum number of $V_i$'s for any given function? Excuse my lack of attempts to solve it but this seems utterly non-trivial for me.

Comment: If you want a generic example to see how bad the answer can be, just take the function that has distinct constant values on each different ray terminating at the origin and you see there are uncountably many such non-limits.

Comment: I know that example. But I wanted to know if it is possible in general to count those.

Comment: I suppose it might depend on what you mean by "can we know in general?", but it seems to me the answer is "of course we can't" , since there are uncountably many functions but only countably many algorithms...

Comment: @AskYourself: Then you should make your question more precise. What do you mean "possible in general"? Look, take an arbitrary real-valued function of two real variables $f$. You're interested in the cardinality of the set $S_a$ for $a\in\mathbb{R}^2$ defined as follows: $S_a$ consists of all $b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that there exists a curve $c$ passing through $a$ such that $b=\lim_{x\to a} f\circ c$. Calculating this set, or even just its cardinality, depends very much on particular properties of both $f$ and $a$. It is easy to construct $f$'s where $S_a$ has any desired cardinality.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily have paths corresponding to each real number. Consider $$f(x,y) =
\begin{cases}
c  & y=cx^2, c\neq0 \\
0 & \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

Along every straight line $y=mx$, the limit is $0$. However, along every $c$-scaled parabola, the limit is $c$.

Comment: I know that example. But I wanted to know if it is possible in general to count those.